SQL import file responds with Query OK but no data imported
The Problem explained
Hi everyone, I'm working on a class assignment in a database class and am having an issue. I am given a CSV and need to import the data as the first step. I'm hoping I can get feedback here instead of waiting for office hours.
The command I'm using for import is
LOAD DATA INFILE '/example/file/path.csv'

INTO TABLE example_table

FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

IGNORE 1 ROWS;

The class instructions listed the lines terminated have mixed return types and need to be \r\n. I triple checked the file path. I exited the MySQL console to run the 'head /example/file/path.csv' to see if there were contents to the file and there are contents. I've used this command in the class before and was able to import data with it. Nothing as far as I can tell has changed about the environment I am working within.
The exact return I get is
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Records: 0 Deleted: 0 Skipped: 0 Warnings: 0

An example of the file contents is



Vehicle ID
State
Repair
Reason
YEAR
Make
Body Type




1844210000000
AL
Battery replacement
Dead battery
2016
RAM
1500 4WD Quad Cab 140.5" SLT


3429310000000
AR
Windshield replacement
Crack
2019
Chevrolet Silverado
1500 4WD Double Cab 143.5" LT w/1LT



The DESCRIBE of the example_table is
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| vehicle_ID | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| state      | varchar(2)   | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| repair     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| reason     | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| year       | year         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| make       | varchar(25)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| body_type  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

I just reliezed I hadn't set the primary key yet but that shouldn't affect it I wouldn't think. I checked the fields in the CSV and they all appear to be acceptable data types for what I've defined.
Things I've tried

I've compared the data types to what's in the CSV and (Without going through thousands of lines) none of the VARCHAR lengths exceed what I've defined

All vehicle_ID fields are integers

Per MySQL documentation year can take an integer length of four and all data inputs are exactly four in length.

I've ensured the file has contents

I've ensured the path I'm using is correct

I've restarted the MySQL session

I've ensured I'm in the correct database and have a table that corresponds to where I'm directing the import.


I feel as though I'm missing something right in front of me and I can't place it yet and that might be due to my lack of experience in MySQL, sorry!
UPDATES AS REQUESTED
Raw data from the CSV, just a few lines.
'Vehicle ID,State,Repair ,Reason,YEAR ,Make,Body Type \n15241383936,AL,Battery replacement,Dead battery,2016,RAM ,"1500 4WD Quad Cab 140.5"" SLT"\n15241383936,AL,Dent Repair  Left Fender,Collision,2016,RAM ,"1500 4WD Quad Cab 140.5"" SLT"\n60965535744,AL,Battery replacement,Dead battery,2016,RAM ,"1500 4WD Quad Cab 140.5"" SLT"\n60965535744,AL,Tire repair,Flat- reparable,2016,RAM ,"1500 4WD Quad Cab 140.5"" SLT"\n60965535744,AL,Tire replacement,Flat- hole not reparable,2016,RAM ,"1500 4WD Quad Cab 140.5"" SLT"\n1.37172E+11,AL,Battery replacement,Dead battery,2017,Chevrolet Silverado ,"1500 4WD Double Cab 143.5"" LT w/1LT"\n


I would venture that your line separator is incorrect and thus the entire file is read into a single line and skipped. This question is impossible to be answered without seeing the raw data you are trying to import.

@Shadow I've added some lines copied from the CSV raw

That's not enough. We need to see the raw data as we can't tell if your column and line separators are correct looking at a html table.

@Shadow I'm confused because I was under the impression that CSV files store tabular data in plain text so should the plain text of copying pasting be the same? I unfortunately can't provide the file because it has a mixture of sample data and real data. Can you explain what you're looking for? If this is too tedious, I can delete the post and just seek office hours, Thanks for your insight!

@Shadow never mind It took me a moment to better understand what you were saying, I'm sorry. I updated the raw and it looks to me there is only one line terminator \n from what I've gathered. Does this look correct to you as far as the data you'd need?

I found the raw data by using python in console. I read the file in and output the read() method to see the return character used.
@Shadow I modified the command to be just /n as the line terminator and I got a different error that a data type was invalid. My vehicle_ID field was too large and needed to be a BIGINT instead but after modifying that field and running the updated command I was able to import all lines successfully! I would love to give you some credit for the help because I didn't even think that was going to be an issue so if you want to write up an answer I can select it!

You use LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' whereas your file sample uses '\n' as a linebreak. So the file does not contain specified delimiter, and the whole file is interpreted as 1-line one which is skipped due to IGNORE 1 ROWS. Also your value for Vehicle ID is too big for to be stored in INTEGER datatype column.
